# Friend needs help with a tourist visa to come into Canada

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, chinese-citizens, proof-of-ties

my friend has been having issues with getting a tourist visa for his wife. They are both residing in China. He is a Canadian citizen and she is a Chinese citizen.

Here is his message to anyone able to assist in quotes.

> Situation:
>   - I am a Canadian citizen working and living in China
>   - I have a wife who is Chinese
>   - We have property, savings in China, with the intention to stay in China
>
> What we want:
>   - to obtain a tourist VISA for my wife so we can visit Canada where my parents live, together
>
> Problem:  We have applied for a tourist visa 3 times within the last
>   three years, about a year apart, but have gotten rejections for all
>   three attempts.
>
> The last application's rejection notes from ATIP ONLY noted down
>   Family and Financial ties to Canada seemed stronger than home country
>   and travel purpose seemed unclear - no other financial, travel
>   experiences, etc. reasons.
>
> I feel that it is because of my Canadian Citizen status that is making
>   the VO think she will overstay, but if I were not Canadian, with my
>   parents there, she would have no reasons to visit Canada in the first
>   place.
>
> My question is:
>
> What or how should I apply next time to address this? I feel that this
>   reason is quite subjective. And we wrote a clear letter stating that
>   we plan to live in China, and our purpose is to visit for about a week
>   with dates specified.
>
> on our second application, we didn't go too in depth about my plans in
>   China; so when they said family ties, it was understandable, but the
>   last one, we provided so much showing my intentions of staying in
>   China and that we will only go back to visit - we have the spousal
>   sponsorship route, so why would we do something illegal?
>
> We are not considering sponsorship at this moment because we fear that
>   if we get the green card and let it expire (not go back or stay in
>   Canada), they might not give us another pass when we really do want to
>   go back.
>
> This is my first time on the forum, so if I made any mistakes, please
>   forgive me. I am truly at blank with this problem because I have
>   contacted VISA agencies and they don't really know, and getting a
>   lawyer is too expensive without a clear go ahead.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Your question mentions property and savings in China, does your friend’s wife have a job and family there too? Does she have a travel history?

Comment: He says "Wife has a job now (contracted for three years), all of her family members are here (brother, sister, parents), she has travel history ( Thailand, Singapore, Malaysia). The last rejection reason did not state travel history as a reason. Simply, ties to Canada higher than China, purpose of travel unclear."